# SQL with 3 criteria using Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Morning All

I am using Access 2010 and currently have the below SQL which works fine:

**Code:**

```
DELETE DISTINCTROW tbl_added.*
FROM tbl_added INNER JOIN tbl_removed ON (tbl_added.SPECIAL_NEED_TYPE = tbl_removed.SPECIAL_NEED_TYPE) AND (tbl_added.NUM_CUST = tbl_removed.NUM_CUST);
```

I am trying to add another criteria but getting an error:

**Code:**

```
DELETE DISTINCTROW tbl_added.*
FROM tbl_added INNER JOIN tbl_removed ON (tbl_added.SPECIAL_NEED_TYPE = tbl_removed.SPECIAL_NEED_TYPE) AND (tbl_added.NUM_CUST = tbl_removed.NUM_CUST) AND (tbl_added.ADDED_REMOVAL_DT < tbl_removed.ADDED_REMOVAL_DT) ;
```

**Error Received:**

> Could not delete from specified tables

The last criteria I have added is a date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When joining on any operator that is not `=`, your recordset becomes non-updateable. That means that you can't edit or delete.

You could move all comparisons to the `WHERE` clause, and use a `CROSS JOIN` instead, like this:

```
DELETE DISTINCTROW tbl_added.*
FROM tbl_added, tbl_removed 
WHERE (tbl_added.SPECIAL_NEED_TYPE = tbl_removed.SPECIAL_NEED_TYPE) AND (tbl_added.NUM_CUST = tbl_removed.NUM_CUST) AND (tbl_added.ADDED_REMOVAL_DT < tbl_removed.ADDED_REMOVAL_DT) ;
```

However, that's still not updateable, since a `CROSS JOIN` is not updateable.

The solution is to keep all `=` comparisons in the `INNER JOIN`, and move all other comparisons to the `WHERE` clause:

```
DELETE DISTINCTROW tbl_added.*
FROM tbl_added INNER JOIN tbl_removed ON (tbl_added.SPECIAL_NEED_TYPE = tbl_removed.SPECIAL_NEED_TYPE) AND (tbl_added.NUM_CUST = tbl_removed.NUM_CUST) 
WHERE (tbl_added.ADDED_REMOVAL_DT < tbl_removed.ADDED_REMOVAL_DT) ;
```

This keeps the recordset updateable, and still allows you to use a `<` operator.

Answer (score 0):

In Access SQL you can't join on "<".

You'll have to use a subquery of some kind or create a temp table with those IDs to delete, then join to this.

**Edit**:

Well, you "can" but not in the GUI designer (see comment from Erik).

So, add the join in the GUI designer the usual way. That will create a join using "=". Then switch to SQL view and change "=" to "<".

It should now run without an error, but you will not be able to switch back to the GUI designer.

Comment: Eh... Yes you can. Depending on the circumstances, it might not be update-able, you might need a _lot_ of parentheses, and you can't view it in design view, but you can certainly join on < (you can join on all comparison operators afaik).

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: You are right. I've edited the answer to include the option. I think, however, I would prefer to move such joins to a _where_ clause.

Comment: That's certainly preferable (for INNER JOINs, at least). I was just about to write up an answer clarifying that you should move those to a where clause, and that if you do, that makes the recordset updateable (OP gets this error because it's not updateable), but feel free to incorporate that in your answer.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: Oh, good. Please go ahead if you are at it. I wouldn't have the time right now anyway.